# 'quark-xpress' tag should be 'quark-quarkxpress'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Given that Quark is the company, QuarkXPress is the actual name of the product (http://quark.com/en/Products/QuarkXPress/) and other software uses a strict 'vendor-product' format.

It's a bit long-winded, and one could argue for 'quarkxpress' instead, but 'quark-xpress' does imply there is a product called XPress.

Comment: Agreed.  Retagged to 'feature request' since it's more of a mis-use of the tag than a bug.  I lean towards 'quarkxpress' since we don't have too many (any?) other quark questions - but either way works (just my 2 cents).  I attempted to retag 'quark-xpress' to 'quarkxpress', but the tag engine is ignoring the dash.  Looks like we need help from a developer...

Comment: Huh. They're still in business. Who knew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone ahead and done two things:

1. `quark-xpress` is now renamed to `quarkxpress`.
2. `quark-quarkxpress` is a synonym of `quarkxpress`. It's [easy enough to swap synonyms](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all) later if need be.